# cudaMemcpy returns cudaErrorInvalidArgument when reading from Device to Host, unclear why

Tags: c++, cuda

first post here. I'm currently working on a project that requires writing a large 2d array (on the order of 1,000,000x7) into my GPU, doing some computation, and returning it to the Host. Since I want to do so quickly and with such a large array, I attempted to flatten the array to help pass it into the GPU fairly straightforwardly. The array successfully writes (or at least cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy both return cudaSuccess when I write to the device), but when I try to read it out cudaMemcpy returns an invalid argument error.

I've not been able to figure out why this is, since I think I should be writing a valid 1d array (flattened) onto the device and reading it back out, and I thought I was feeding the right arguments to do this. The only results for this error I've found online involve swapping the dst and src arguments for cudaMemcpy, but I think I've got those right here.

This is a simplified version of my code that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void alloc2dArray(float ** &arr, unsigned long int rows, unsigned long int cols){ 

    arr = new float*[rows];

    arr[0] = new float[rows * cols];

    for(unsigned long int i = 1; i < rows; i++) arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + cols;
}

void write2dArrayToGPU(float ** arr, float * devPtr, unsigned long int rows, unsigned long int cols){

    if(cudaSuccess != cudaMalloc((void**)&devPtr, sizeof(float) * rows * cols)) cerr << "cudaMalloc Failed";

    if(cudaSuccess != cudaMemcpy(devPtr, arr[0], sizeof(float) * rows * cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)) cerr << "cudaMemcpy Write Failed";
}

void read2dArrayFromGPU(float ** arr, float * devPtr, unsigned long int rows, unsigned long int cols){

    if(cudaSuccess != cudaMemcpy(arr[0], devPtr, sizeof(float) * rows * cols, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)) cerr << "cudaMemcpy Read Failed" << endl;
}

int main(){

int R = 100;
int C = 7;

cout << "Allocating an " << R << "x" << C << " array ...";
float ** arrA;
alloc2dArray(arrA, R, C);


cout << "Assigning some values ...";
for(int i = 0; i < R; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < C; j++){
        arrA[i][j] = i*C + j;
    }
}
cout << "Done!" << endl;


cout << "Writing to the GPU ...";
float * Darr = 0;
write2dArrayToGPU(arrA, Darr, R, C);
cout << " Done!" << endl;

cout << "Allocating second " << R << "x" << C << " array ...";
float ** arrB;
alloc2dArray(arrB, R, C);
cout << "Done!" << endl;

cout << "Reading from the GPU into the new array ...";
read2dArrayFromGPU(arrB, Darr, R, C);


}
```

I compile and run this on my laptop with

```
 $nvcc -arch=sm_30 test.cu -o test
 $optirun cuda-memcheck ./test
```

and get the result:

```
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Allocating an 100x7 array ...Assigning some values ...Done!
Writing to the GPU ... Done!
Allocating second 100x7 array ...Done!
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidValue (error 11) due to "invalid argument" on CUDA API call to cudaMemcpy. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
Reading from the GPU into the new array ...=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/nvidia-bumblebee/libcuda.so.1 [0x2ef343]
cudaMemcpy Read Failed=========     Host Frame:./test [0x38c6f]
=========     Host Frame:./test [0x2f08]
=========     Host Frame:./test [0x3135]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf1) [0x20401]
=========     Host Frame:./test [0x2c6a]

=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
```

I'm moderately new to CUDA, and still learning, so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: CUDA is not related to C.

Comment: you can't pass-by-value `devPtr` as a single pointer argument to a function, do a `cudaMalloc` on that pointer, and then expect the assigned pointer value to show up in the calling environment.  This is a common mistake with pass-by-value, and there are certainly other similar questions.  Such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826380/cuda-allocation-and-return-array-from-gpu-to-cpu). You might want to study the answer there, your question is arguably a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Robert Crovella for pointing me in the right direction with a comment above, and linking a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826380/cuda-allocation-and-return-array-from-gpu-to-cpu).

The gist is that by passing `devPtr` by value rather than by pointer or by reference into my GPU `write` and `read` functions, the cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy functions were acting only on a copy in the function scope.

Two solutions - (both of these run without throwing errors for me)

First: Pass `devPtr` by reference into `write2dArrayToGPU` and `read2dArrayFromGPU` the solution then looks like.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void alloc2dArray(float ** &arr, unsigned long int rows, unsigned long int cols){

    arr = new float*[rows];

    arr[0] = new float[rows * cols];

    for(unsigned long int i = 1; i < rows; i++) arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + cols;
}

//changed float * devPtr to float *  &devPtr
void write2dArrayToGPU(float ** arr, float * &devPtr, unsigned long int rows, unsigned long int cols){

    if(cudaSuccess != cudaMalloc((void**)&devPtr, sizeof(float) * rows * cols)) cerr << "cudaMalloc Failed";

    if(cudaSuccess != cudaMemcpy(devPtr, arr[0], sizeof(float) * rows * cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)) cerr << "cudaMemcpy Write Failed";
}

//changed float * devPtr to float * &devPtr
void read2dArrayFromGPU(float ** arr, float * &devPtr, unsigned long int rows, unsigned long int cols){

    if(cudaSuccess != cudaMemcpy(arr[0], devPtr, sizeof(float) * rows * cols, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)) cerr << "cudaMemcpy Read Failed" << endl;
}

int main(){

int R = 100;
int C = 7;

cout << "Allocating an " << R << "x" << C << " array ...";
float ** arrA;
alloc2dArray(arrA, R, C);


cout << "Assigning some values ...";
for(int i = 0; i < R; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < C; j++){
        arrA[i][j] = i*C + j;
    }
}
cout << "Done!" << endl;


cout << "Writing to the GPU ...";
float * Darr = 0;
write2dArrayToGPU(arrA, Darr, R, C);
cout << " Done!" << endl;

cout << "Allocating second " << R << "x" << C << " array ...";
float ** arrB;
alloc2dArray(arrB, R, C);
cout << "Done!" << endl;

cout << "Reading from the GPU into the new array ...";
read2dArrayFromGPU(arrB, Darr, R, C);


}
```

Second: Pass `devPtr` by pointer so the solution looks like

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void alloc2dArray(float ** &arr, unsigned long int rows, unsigned long int cols){

    arr = new float*[rows];

    arr[0] = new float[rows * cols];

    for(unsigned long int i = 1; i < rows; i++) arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + cols;
}

//changed float * devPtr to float ** devPtr
void write2dArrayToGPU(float ** arr, float ** devPtr, unsigned long int rows, unsigned long int cols){

    if(cudaSuccess != cudaMalloc((void**)devPtr, sizeof(float) * rows * cols)) cerr << "cudaMalloc Failed";

    if(cudaSuccess != cudaMemcpy(*devPtr, arr[0], sizeof(float) * rows * cols, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)) cerr << "cudaMemcpy Write Failed";
}

//changed float * devPtr to float ** devPtr
void read2dArrayFromGPU(float ** arr, float ** devPtr, unsigned long int rows, unsigned long int cols){

    if(cudaSuccess != cudaMemcpy(arr[0], *devPtr, sizeof(float) * rows * cols, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)) cerr << "cudaMemcpy Read Failed" << endl;
}

int main(){

int R = 100;
int C = 7;

cout << "Allocating an " << R << "x" << C << " array ...";
float ** arrA;
alloc2dArray(arrA, R, C);


cout << "Assigning some values ...";
for(int i = 0; i < R; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < C; j++){
        arrA[i][j] = i*C + j;
    }
}
cout << "Done!" << endl;


cout << "Writing to the GPU ...";
float * Darr = 0;
write2dArrayToGPU(arrA, &Darr, R, C); \\changed Darr to &Darr
cout << " Done!" << endl;

cout << "Allocating second " << R << "x" << C << " array ...";
float ** arrB;
alloc2dArray(arrB, R, C);
cout << "Done!" << endl;

cout << "Reading from the GPU into the new array ...";
read2dArrayFromGPU(arrB, &Darr, R, C); // changed Darr to &Darr


}
```